# Run Spring cron job at midnight

Tags: java, spring, cron, cron-task

Do you know what is the cron expression for Spring *@Scheduled* annotation to run at mid night?

This is the cron I currently use. I am not sure if its right.

> 59 59 23 * * *

Please note that this is not quartz, its Spring so there are only 6 places, not 7.

Answer (score 4):

Use [cronmaker](http://cronmaker.com) for generating and verifying cron's

```
0 0 0 1/1 * ?
```

Answer (score 1):

0 0 0 * * * will trigger cron job in spring at mid night at 00:00

Answer (score 1):

This will Run the Job exactly at Midnight

0 0 0 * * ?

Comment: What is the benefit over the existing answer which claims the same?